# 10 x 3 meter poster or billboard

Tags: posters, billboard

https://www.flickr.com/photos/152264312@N04/35952408580/in/dateposted-public/

my client wants to print this photo on a poster of 10x4 meter board. i had all the files or I can make a new one too. please tell what should be the resolution and pixels etc.

Comment: Ask the printer. Guess: 50 or 100 dpi

Comment: The more the merrier. Make it 300 pixels per inch, multiply 300 by however many inches are in 10 meters, then do same for height. That's your target size. I hope your photos are high resolution.

Answer (score -1):

We cannot answer this.

The only person who can is the one printing it.